# How to center a text field on iOS?

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, constraints

I am having trouble using constraints to center a text field both vertically and horizontally.

I have a tabbed iPhone application project open in Visual Studio Community 2015. The project is restricted to portrait mode only, so no landscape to worry about.

How do I center a text field in a `UIViewController` both vertically and horizontally, so that when I re-size my screen (iPhone 6 screen size to 5s screen size) it stays centered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the visual studio designer you just need to put the `TextField` on your view. Then click on it - if you see circles instead of rectangles click again. You should see a square in the center of the field. Drag it to the vertical and horizontal line of the superview outside the `TextField`.
If it's still orange, you need height and weight to adjust.

[image: Initial TextField - click again to switch mode]

[image: Setting center cosntraints]
[image: Setting Width constraint]

Then you should see your constraints like this:

[image]